Error while reading metadata in jBoss8 management console
I'm working in the jBoss8 management console, however, whenever I press the plus button (for example to add a profile or an interface) I get the error "Error while reading metadata".
I do not have more details about the error to be able to identify the cause of the problem.
Does anyone know why this happens?


